# Matlab - Find 2d matrix values in 3d matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, compare

I have the following problem. I have two matrices, one 2d matrix of size X,Y with a set of terrain heights taken from a DEM file and a 3d matrix of size X,Y,Z with Z height values from 0 to 5000 meters for each (X,Y) point.

I want to compare, for each (X,Y) point its DEM height with the column of Z height values and take the closest one. For example:

```
dem(1,1) = 1850 %actual height of the terrain at point (1,1)
heights(1,1,:) = 0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000 %column of heights at point (1,1)
```

If I use the function "find" I get the following error:

```
find(heights > dem, 1)
Error using  > 
Number of array dimensions must match for binary array op.
```

Is there any solution to this that doesn't require two for loops?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: if `X` and `Y` stay the same, isn't the question gonna be reduced to a comparison betwenn `Z` arrays? Cause I expect that the coordinates of each point are unvaried between the **2d** and **3d** representation. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, for each point it is a comparison between a vector of length Z and a value. It could be done with `find(height(x,y,:)>dem(x,y))` for each point. However I would like a solution for the whole matrix at the same time, without looping through X and Y coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reduce this to a loop over a single dimension using `bsxfun`:

```
heights = rand(10, 10, 10);
dem = rand(5, 1);
bsxfun(@gt, heights(1, :, :), dem)

    [returns a 5x10x10 matrix]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was just looking at this function:
`result = bsxfun(@ge, heights, dem);`
It works just as expected.

Comment: be aware that you are looping anyway!

Comment: No you're not, except over the single dimension that `bsxfun` can't deal with... `bsxfun` does a `repmat` to make your single-dimensioned data the same size as your multidimensional data, then does the whole operation at once.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to define your data as:

```
dem(1,1) = 1850;
heights(1,1,:) = [0; 1000; 2000; 3000; 4000; 5000];
```

Now, `find(heights > dem, 1)` yeilds

```
ans =

     3
```

which is the expected result, the index of `2000`.

Comment: In the example I give values of just one point of the matrix. My aim is to do it for the whole set of (X,Y) points at the same time.